# div halfway down page

Tags: html, css

I am not exactly the best at CSS so I don't really understand where the origin of this issue came from. I have a very minimal amount of CSS which is why I don't understand this. Below is the image of what is happening. And below the image is the CSS/HTML. The problem is that "Hello nick!!!" is about 150px from the green.

[image: html and css problem]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/6a89e5b95726736e4c48cab53d26b5c2.png))</sub>

CSS:

```
#sidebarContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar li {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}

#sidebar li.active {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#sidebar li:hover {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#sidebar li a {
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#contentContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebarContainer">
    <ul id="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}
        <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Favourites</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Discussion</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        {% endblock %}
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried veritical-align : top; ?

Comment: please make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @BrettWeber Wow that was a newbie mistake on my part. Thanks for the help! haha

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: welcome. :) I use that a lot so I am glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 vertical-align : top;
```

Add that to to #contentContainer styling. 
This should push that div up where you are wanting it to be. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding float to #sidebarContainer

```
    float:left;
```